# How to run smtLib file using Z3 on Ubuntu?

Tags: z3, z3py

For example I have a smtLib file 'encoding.smt'. Now I want to run this file by z3 (standalone exe) with a given timeout and memory allocation on a Ubuntu machine. Like :

```
$./z3 encoding.smt 240(sec) 6(GB)
```

I have downloaded ubuntu 32 bit zip file from Z3 download page. What I have to do now? There is a z3 application on the 'bin' folder. Shall I need to change any environment variable - if I want to write any Z3py script under Ubuntu ?

Can any one give me the steps for both (running **.smt file** by **standalone Z3 with given timeout and memory** and running **.smt file from z3py script with given timeout and memory**)

Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: I got the options for timeout, memory of z3 (executable) using the help command $ ./z3 -h. But Can any one tell me how I can set the options in Z3py script? like - solver.set('timeout', 240) solver.set('memory', 6) !! I don't know how to set these options. I have seen some post about timeout but how can I set memory limit. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

These options are called `timeout` and `memory_max_size` respectively. In the python interface, they can be set as follows:

```
set_option(timeout='60')
set_option(memory_max_size='1000')
```

A list of (global and module) options can be obtained by running `z3 -p`. These options can also be set on the command line, e.g.,

```
z3 encoding.smt2 timeout=60 memory_max_size=1000
```